# How to convert .bat code to .php code

Tags: php, batch-file

I want use webscreencapture to make a web screenshot. if I save the below code in a screenshot.bat, and then click it, it can catch the two web screenshots.

```
webscreencapture.exe http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SLyG0mUnw4A e:\www\111\1.jpg
webscreencapture.exe http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=izUxI-k01CU e:\www\111\2.jpg
```

Now I want to convert .bat code to .php code. I use:

```
<?php
$cmd = 'webscreencapture.exe http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SLyG0mUnw4A e:\www\111\1.jpg';
sleep(1);
$cmd = 'webscreencapture.exe http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=izUxI-k01CU e:\www\111\1.jpg';
system($cmd);
?>
```

It just gets the second web screenshot. It doesn't seem to run the first command. Where's the problem? Thanks.

By the way, webscreencapture can not set a time delay, and can not screenshot a youtube movie. Can anyone recommend something that can?

Comment: By the way, how to post a php code? Forgive I am a newer.

Comment: Select it an press the format code button. It looks like two rows of binary digits. Alternatively, indent all lines by 4 spaces.

Comment: Hi thanks, now I konw how to post a php code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't execute your first `$cmd`.  You just replace it after sleeping for a second.

Comment: Thanks, friends, I am too careless, may be I shall have a rest.

Answer (score 1):

Your assigning cmd to the new string before even calling the first command.  Also, the filenames appear to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You never actually bother ever *calling* the first command. You have to call `system($cmd)` after assigning the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the main problem seems to be that you only call `system($cmd)` once.

`$cmd` is just a variable that contains the command to call.  The `system($cmd)` is what actually executes it.